# Remove/replace special characters in column values?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table column containing values which I would like to remove all the hyphens from. The values may contain more than one hyphen and vary in length.

Example: for all values I would like to replace `123 - ABCD - efghi` with `123ABCDefghi`.

What is the easiest way to remove all hyphens & update all column values in the table?

Comment: `replace('xxx - xxxx', ' - ','')` is probably the easiest

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `regexp_replace` function to left only the digits and letters, like this:

```
update mytable
   set myfield = regexp_replace(myfield, '[^\w]+','');
```

Which means that everything that is not a digit or a letter or an underline will be replaced by nothing (that includes `-, space, dot, comma`, etc).

If you want to also include the `_` to be replaced (`\w` will leave it) you can change the regex to `[^\w]+|_`.

Or if you want to be strict with the characters that must be removed you use: `[- ]+` in this case here a dash and a space.

Also as suggested by [Luiz Signorelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1167483/luizsignorelli) you can use to replace all occurrences:

```
    update mytable
       set myfield = regexp_replace(myfield, '[^\w]+','','g');
```

Comment: use `regexp_replace(myfield, '[^\w]+','','g');` to replace all occurences

Comment: Hi @LuizSignorelli You can add an answer of your own, but please if you do so, explain the difference you provided (eg, why is using `g` modifier better or necessary for the OP's problem) :) Cheers,

Comment: It would be great if the downvoter could explain what's wrong so I can improve however is possible, please :)

Comment: And If I want to remove all caracters are not alphanumerics but keep dash (-) and space ( ). How to do it ?

Comment: @NIF in that case you can use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` this means ranges of a to z lower, A to Z upper and 0 to 9

Comment: this doesn't leave the spaces

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

`update table 
set column = format('%s%s', left(column, 3), right(column, -6));`

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: see Edit, i should have clarified that the strings before and after the hyphen can vary in length & the entire value may contain more than one hyphen (remove all).

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer