# Postgresql: Remove hyphens and whitespaces

Tags: postgresql

I am currently working on DB data which contains whitespaces and hyphens. I searched over the net and found this [Remove/replace special characters in column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44191167/remove-replace-special-characters-in-column-values) . I tried to follow the answer but I am still getting hyphens. I tried playing around with it, I can only remove the whitespace

```
conn_p = p.connect("dbname='p_test' user='postgres' password='postgres' host='localhost'")
conn_t = p.connect("dbname='t_mig1' user='postgres' password='postgres' host='localhost'")

cur_p = conn_p.cursor()
cur_t = conn_t.cursor()

cur_t.execute("SELECT CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(studentnumber, ' ', '') as integer), firstname, middlename, lastname FROM sprofile")
rows = cur_t.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print "Inserting ", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]
    cur_p.execute(""" INSERT INTO "a_recipient" (id, first_name, middle_name, last_name) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') """ % (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))

cur_p.commit()
cur_pl.close()
cur_t.close()
```

What I would like to achieve is if I got a studentnumber of 001-2012-1456, it will be displayed as 000120121456.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To wipe out all characters in a set efficiently use [`translate`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html). It takes a set of characters to translate into another set of characters. If the other set is empty it deletes them.

```
test=> select translate('001-2012-145 6', '- ', '');
  translate  
-------------
 00120121456
```

---

While `translate` is simpler and faster for this particular job, it's important to know how to use regexes for others. To do it with `regexp_replace` there's two changes you need to make.

First, you have to match the *set* of `-` and  as `[- ]`.

Then, you have to specify to replace all occurrences, otherwise it will stop after the first one. That's done with the `g` flag.

```
test=> select regexp_replace('001-2012-145 6', '[- ]', '', 'g');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 00120121456
```

Here's a tutorial on [POSIX regular expressions and character sets](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

Comment: Hi Sir, this removes the starting zeros, my result is 120121456

Comment: @tangoward It does not remove starting zeros, as shown above. You're probably still casting to integer, integers do not keep starting zeros. If you want to keep starting zeros, don't cast to integer. Leave it as a string.

Comment: Hi Sir, this is what I'm getting. Please disregard the "null" error, I will fix them. Failing row contains (120130548, null, null, null) and my code is SELECT TRANSLATE(studentnumber, '- ', '')

Comment: @tangoward Hello. There's two things to check. One is that `studentnumber` is what you think it is, which you can check with `SELECT studentnumber, TRANSLATE(studentnumber, '- ', '')`. If that looks ok then it's likely that the code you're using to run the query and fetch the result is translating the result to an integer. Try it in `psql` (the Postgres shell) to be sure. If it's your code, you should ask another question about how to keep it a string.

Comment: Yeah, it does work on psql. I updated my post for the code.

Comment: It's the problem with the ID field. My bad. It should have been student_id. I'm really sorry.

Comment: @tangoward No worries! These things happen.

Comment: should this select translate be inside the for loop too? Also I just noticed that some of the fields that I have (father name and mother name) are in one field instead of (f_first_name, f_m_name, f_l_name). I will post another thread on how to parse this. I am bit lost in using string_to_array()

Comment: @tangoward No, it does not need to be in the for loop. Ideally you should not be using `fetchall` because that loads the entire table into memory, it can be a lot of memory. Instead, iterate one row at a time with `for row in cur_t:`. Also, if this were in a single database you could do all this with one query: `insert into a_recipient (id, first_name, middle_name, last_name) select translate(student_number, '- ', '')::integer, firstname, middlename, lastname) from sprofile`. I'll look at your other question.

Comment: Okay got it. These are in both different databases but under public schema. Also, here's the link to my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149167/postgresql-data-array-to-string-clarification/50149314?noredirect=1#comment87316666_50149314

Comment: Hey, sorry to bump this thread. I just want to know the reason why I can't loop through the studentnumber using `for row in cur_t: print row['studentnumber']` but I can access it using `row[0]`. This happens when I use TRANSLATE on studentnumber.

Error:
`x = self._index[x]
KeyError: 'studentnumber'
x = self._index[x]
KeyError: 'studentnumber'
`

Comment: @tangoward When you `select studentnumber, ...` the column is `studentnumber` and that will be available as `row['studentnumber']`. When you `select translate(studentnumber, '- ', ''), ...` the column is `translate(studentnumber, '- ', '')` and will be available as `row['translate(studentnumber, '- ', '')']` (or similar). `print vars(row)` will (probably) reveal this. To get that function as "studentnumber" you need to [give the column an alias with `as`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). `select translate(studentnumber, '- ', '') as studentnumber`. That's my best guess.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly the problem. I only figured it out yesterday that when I use Translate(), the column name will be changed to the function name, hence using the row['translate'] as the key.

Answer (score 7):

Its very simple to use inbuilt **translate** function.

**Example:**

```
select translate('001-2012-145 6', '- ', '');
```

**Output of above command :**
00120121456