# Word count for indic language in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, text, bigdata

I want to count the number of words in the link below.
https://storymirror.com/read/story/gujarati/ywsh5l6o/baagbaan-ek-phuulno-nirnnya

In Microsoft Word it's properly counting, however, in the code below, I am not able to get the correct data.

```
length(REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(original_content,'"',''),'\\''+', '''', 'g')).
```

I tried multiple options such as

```
1. REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(content,'"',''),'\\''+', '''', 'g')
2. array_length(regexp_split_to_array(trim(content), E'\\W+'), 1),
```

Comment: Below link has a similar answer. Please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44207686/7409834

Comment: That is completely different.

Comment: Anyone who can answer the above question? I felt stackoverflow is a place of experts.